# Enabling WebGl without the Windows shell

Tags: c#, windows, webgl, windows-shell, windows-explorer

I am trying to make my own Windows shell(don't ask) but the problem is: when I use Google Chrome while the native shell(Windows Explorer) is not running, Chrome doesn't display web pages properly unless I turn off the GPU accelerated composting.  It seems to me that WebGL isn't drawing page content at all.  What do I have to do to enable WebGL while Windows Explorer is not running? [I am using C#.net]

Note that if I go to a page like get.webgl.org/ nothing will display no matter what.

If you can answer this question, you are a genius.